# HTML, CSS Edit

Tags: html, css, xhtml

i wrote some html code and want to edit its view using the css

```
                <div id="contact_4" name="contact" >
                <input type="checkbox" id="chk_4" class="contactChk"/>
                <img height="25" width="25" alt="" src="Images/Contacts/1.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 35px;"/>
                <span class="contactItem" id="contactName_4" name="contactName">
                    Amr ElGarhy
                </span>
                <img src="Images/Common/Motiva.png" alt=""/>
                <br/>
            </div>
```

[alt text http://igurr.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/500x400/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.00.01.73/OneContact.JPG](http://igurr.com/resized-image.ashx/__size/500x400/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.00.01.73/OneContact.JPG)

What i want to do is making the Text and images align vertical in the main div, please if anyone know how to do so without using any tables and just using CSS, and advice me also if i must edit the html itself.

UPDATE:
I want everything in the main div t be aligned vertical middle. as you can see in the image that text, checkbox and the 2 images are aligned bottom by default which i want to override.

Comment: You'll have to give a better explanation of what youre trying to do

Comment: Vertical middle or horizontal middle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
#contact_4 * {      
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline;
}
```

The "display: inline;" isn't necessary if you have no other styles changing those elements display types.

P.S. There's no "name" attribute for div and span elements.

Comment: Your answer is the simpler while others solutions can apply as well.
didn't know that its too easy like that, but sure for experience person ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no guru at CSS, but maybe putting these on all of the elements would help:

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
```